# e-commerce in Tornado (non-blocking) VS Flask (WSGI)

Tags: python, e-commerce, wsgi, flask, tornado

am trying to develop a e-commerce plateforme using python and nosql, as framework i'm between two: tornado and flask; so my question is simple:

Which one is suited for e-commerce: WSGI-like application (using Flask) or a non-blocking application (using Tornado)?

NB: the e-commerce will manage products, and users (without making chat system) but will include a notification system (like facebook one: someone -a friend- sold somthing...), so which is better for such situation?

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but as an alternative way django with satchmo is very suitable for that sort of projects.

Comment: there is "no" in computer science, the only thing is: can be easy or hard to implement!
i think it will be a challenge that i'll try to do :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two flask estensions you might leverage:

https://github.com/MediaSapiens/flamaster and

https://bitbucket.org/lost_theory/flask-stripe-blueprint/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a really good python-based e-commerce solution is still hard.

**Some things to look at**

Satchless http://satchless.com This is a flask-compatible framework agnostic shopping cart solution.

Saleor http://getsaleor.com (django not flask or tornado)

Saleor which is django-based seems more mature and currently maintained.  Last update was [19 days ago on github](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor).  I would look into this.

The same developers of Saleor also created [django-payments](https://github.com/mirumee/django-payments/).